# Windows Form Application "Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types."

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2015

It might just be me but I haven't found any information to help me with this anywhere on the internet. The error comes under the `EnterButton` in the code. And when I look into it, it comes up with:

> Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

```
Private Sub EnterButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnterButton.Click
    MessageBox.Show("Hello", "hello")
End Sub
```

I'm not even sure if this is enough to know what is wrong. Let me know if you need to see more of the code to help me out.

Comment: I should add that when I comment out the code, it seems to run perfectly.

Comment: You probably need to change your declaration to something like `Public WithEvents EnterButton As Button`...unless you added the button with the forms designer, then you have a problem with the designer file. Also, WithEvents can only be used at a class scope level, if you're creating buttons inside a sub/function you'll need to use AddHandler

Comment: Did you copy that code of the web somewhere?  Generally speaking, you add a `Button` to your form in the designer and then double-click it to generate a `Click` event handler.  That's what someone else would have done to generate that method.  In such cases, you should add the appropriate control to your form, e.g. add a `Button` and name it `EmterButton`. Alternatively, add the control first and double-click it to generate the event handler, then just copy the method body instead of the whole thing.

Comment: Go back to the designer and add/edit a button.  It Name needs to be "EnterButton".

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Handles keyword to wire up an event handler, the variable of the object that you are using the Handles keyword for must be defined WithEvents.

```
Public YourClass

     Private WithEvents EnterButton As New Button()

End YourClass
```